# triton inference server: deploy model with input shape BxN config.pbtxt

Tags: pytorch, triton, tritonserver

I have installed triton inference server with docker,

```
docker run --gpus=1 --rm -p8000:8000 -p8001:8001 -p8002:8002 -v /mnt/data/nabil/triton_server/models:/models nvcr.io/nvidia/tritonserver:22.08-py3 tritonserver --model-repository=/models
```

I have also created the torchscript model from my pytorch model, using

```
from model_ecapatdnn import ECAPAModel
import soundfile as sf
import torch

model_1 = ECAPAModel.ECAPAModel(lr = 0.001, lr_decay = 0.97, C = 1024, n_class = 18505, m = 0.2, s = 30, test_step = 3, gpu = -1)
model_1.load_parameters("/ecapatdnn/model.pt")

model = model_1.speaker_encoder
# Switch the model to eval model
model.eval()

# An example input you would normally provide to your model's forward() method.
example = torch.rand(1, 48000)

# Use torch.jit.trace to generate a torch.jit.ScriptModule via tracing.
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)

# Save the TorchScript model
traced_script_module.save("traced_ecapatdnn_bangasianeng.pt")
```

Now, as you can see, my model takes a tensor with shape `(BxN)`, where B is the batch size.

How do I write the `config.pbtxt` for this model?

Answer (score 0):

So, found the answer. Have to just specify the shape in `config` file. Here is the `config` that works for me.

```
name: "ecapatdnn_bangasianeng"
platform: "pytorch_libtorch"
max_batch_size: 1

input[
{
name: "INPUT__0"
data_type:  TYPE_FP32
dims: [-1]
}
]

output:[
{
name: "OUTPUT__0"
data_type:  TYPE_FP32
dims: [512]
}
]
```